# Unable to upload section of pandas dataframe using one psycopg2 sql query to postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, psycopg2

I have a pandas dataframe that I wish to upload to a PostgreSQL 10.2 database.

The dataframe looks as so:

```
 c1   c2    c3  c4  c5   c6   c7      c8    c9
text text  integer integer  integer  integer  integer  text  geog
```

I am trying to upload the dataframe using psycopg2, in essence upload the first 8 columns (not spatial data) then upload the final column (spatial data), to the database using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2 as ps

d = {'c1':['a', 'b', 'c'], 'c2':['a', 'b', 'c'], 'c3':[0, 1, 2], 'c4':[0, 1, 2], 'c5':[0, 1, 2], 'c6':[0, 1, 2], 'c7':[0, 1, 2], 'c8':['aa|0', 'bb|1', 'cc|2'], 'c9':['87.579 36.798', '88.012 36.234', '87.007 36.009']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

conn_string = "host='localhost' dbname='postgis_24_sample' user='user' password='pwd'"

conn = ps.connect(conn_string)
cursor = conn.cursor()

for i in range(len(self.df)):
    i = i + 1
    upload1 = ('''INSERT INTO public."Table" ("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5", "c6", "c7", "c8") VALUES ('"'{}'"', '"'{}'"', {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, '"'{}'"');''').format(self.df.iloc[0:i, 0:1], self.df.iloc[0:i, 1:2], self.df.iloc[0:i, 2:3], self.df.iloc[0:i, 3:4], self.df.iloc[0:i, 4:5], self.df.iloc[0:i, 5:6], sdf.iloc[0:i, 6:7], self.df.iloc[0:i, 7:8])

    upload2 = ('''INSERT INTO public."Table" ("c9”) VALUES (ST_GeomFromText('POINT('"'{}'"')', 4326))).format(self.iloc[0:i, 8:9])

    cursor.execute(upload1)
    cursor.execute(upload2)

conn.commit()
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

However I have the following error:

"ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "c1"
LINE 1: ...", "c7", "c8", "c9") VALUES ('"'  c1"

I am at a loss for what to do in order to move forward and any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: could it be you forgot one `"` at the `upoload2`?

Comment: Thanks, I did indeed miss an “ on upload2. I have made the correction but still get the same error. It seems to be failing at upload1.

Comment: not sure why you need the `"` on the column names. But in case you do need them, try escaping with `\"`

Comment: @Kieran, can you post a small (3-5 rows) reproducible sample data set? It's not clear how your `c9` column looks like on the Pandas side...

Comment: An alternative would be to use `to_sql` function in `pandas`. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

Comment: @MaxU I have edited my post to include a small reproducible dataset, again any advice you may have will be greatly appreciated.